# jQuerty UI range slider bug after change min value

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-slider

I have one slider in my page, with this code

```
<div id="sale-price-range" class="price-range" data-min="200000" data-max="2000000" data-unit="R$" data-min-field="precoMinVenda" data-max-field="precoMaxVenda" data-increment="100000"></div>
```

My js code is:

```
// Price Range
$(".price-range").each(function() {

    var dataMin = $(this).attr('data-min');
    var dataMax = $(this).attr('data-max');
    var dataUnit = $(this).attr('data-unit');
    var minField = $(this).attr('data-min-field');
    var maxField = $(this).attr('data-max-field');
    var increment = $(this).attr('data-increment');

    $(this).append( "<input type='text' class='first-slider-value' name='"+minField+"' val=''/><input type='text' class='second-slider-value' name='"+maxField+"'/>" );

    $(this).slider({
        range: true,
        min: 0,
        max: dataMax,
        step: increment,
        values: [ dataMin, dataMax ],

        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            event = event;
            if(ui.value < dataMin) {
                return false;
            }
            $(this).find( ".first-slider-value" ).val( dataUnit + " " + ui.values[ 0 ].toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1.") );
            $(this).find( ".second-slider-value" ).val( dataUnit + " " + ui.values[ 1 ].toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1.") );
        },
        stop: function(event,ui) {
            if(ui.value >= dataMin) {
                postAjaxSearch();
            }
        }
    });
     $(this).find( ".first-slider-value" ).val( dataUnit + " " + $( this ).slider( "values", 0 ).toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1.") );
     $(this).find( ".second-slider-value" ).val( dataUnit + " " +  $( this ).slider( "values", 1 ).toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1.") );
});
```

It works very well, but if I try to change 
    min: 0,
To
    min: dataMin,

My slider stop to work (I can't drag it). It continues to call postAjaxSearch();, but it doesn't change max/min value neither move the slider-handle.

Why do I need to change min to dataMin?
Because my slider start from 0, but the slider-handle move from dataMin from dataMax. The range betweem dataMin and 0 is on page, but can't move there. I don't want this, the slider should start from dataMin.

[Work, but with this space on left (min: 0)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZapu.jpg)
[No space, but doesn't work (min: dataMin)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4Qah.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same exact problem, I solved it by using parseInt() on the min value

```
$("#price-slider").slider({
        range: true,
        min: parseInt(price_min),
        max: price_max,
        values: [price_min, price_max],
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            $("#amount").val("$" + ui.values[0] + " - $" + ui.values[1]);
        }
    });
```

I have no idea why this works, it would seem logical that both extremes would work the same but apparently they don't.

Comment: Dennis, I solved it also with parseInt, but I forgot to post the solution here. Thank you, your answer is absolut corret.

Comment: Excellent. Also makes zero sense to me.... but works